# filenotFound when try to create new file on java

Tags: java

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm:ssZ");
        String formattedString = zonedDateTime.format(formatter);
        String fileName = formattedString+"partner"+".csv";
        File newFile = new File(fileName);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile));
        //headers
        writer.write("id,name,logoUrl,status,ctime,mtime"+"\n");
        for(Partner partner : partners){
            System.out.println(partner.getId() + " " + partner.getName());
            writer.write(partner.getId()+","+partner.getName()+","+partner.getStatus()+","+partner.getCtime()+","+partner.getMtime()+"\n");
        }
```

hi guys i have code like that for create a csv file. from convert from my db to csv file... but when i try to create a csv file i got error like FileNotFOUND....    `"message": "java.io.FileNotFoundException: 08/23/2021-08:35:47+0000partner.csv (No such file or directory)",` my question is how to make my file create and when this create to write it ? because i have try to fix this issue... but this issue still exist... thanks guys...

after i can convert it to csv file i need to upload to S3 bucket on my AWS

Comment: Does the system you are running this code on support colons in file names? Or slashes?

Comment: Your file name looks dangerous, for example in Windows FS you can't use neither slashes for dates nor columns for times. Try to use a date formatter with a pattern that only uses dashes for the date and represent the time with something else like dots

Answer (score 0):

Use underscores `_` and not slashes `/` in your Date Pattern. Those characters are not allowed in file names (at least not in windows).

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm_ssZ");
```